# Scala build.sbt: Memcached Plugin for Play framework 2.8.6

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt, memcached

I am trying to upgrade [mumoshu's Memcached Plugin for Play framework](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached), to [Play 2.8.6](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.mumoshu/play2-memcached-play28_2.13/0.11.0), in `build.sbt`.

**The upgrade instructions are:**

For Play 2.6.x and newer: !!! Changed play.modules.cache.* config keys to play.cache.* !!!

```scala
val appDependencies = Seq(
  play.PlayImport.cacheApi,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play26" % "0.9.2"
)
val main = Project(appName).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
  version := appVersion,
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
  resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2" // required to resolve `spymemcached`, the plugin's dependency.
)
```

**Before the upgrade, I had:**

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  ws,  
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play24" % "0.7.0",
  //...
}
```

**After the (unsuccessful) upgrade:**

- the `cache` dependency is not resolved, so I removed it.

The updated `build.sbt` now looks like this:

```
name := "CH07"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `ch07` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  play.sbt.PlayImport.cache,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0"
  //"com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play26" % "0.9.2"
)
val main = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.sbt.PlayScala).settings(
  version := version.value,
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
  resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2" // required to resolve `spymemcached`, the plugin's dependency.
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  //cache,
  ws,

  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.github.ironfish" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-casbah"  % "0.7.6",
  "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

**Errors I am getting:**

```
* build.sbt:
error: value cache is not a member of object play.sbt.PlayImport

* build.sbt:
"com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0"
Intellij says: unresolved artifact. Not resolved or indexed.

* in project/plugins.sbt:
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.6")
Intellij says: unresolved artifact. Not resolved or indexed.
```

Can you see any errors I made in the `build.sbt`?

In other words, I am looking for a working `build.sbt` (and the other required definitions) example for a project that uses Play 2.8.6 and the Memcached Plugin for Play framework 0.9.2. (or highest possible version of the latter).

**UPDATE:**

This is my current configuration which does compile:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "CH07"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `ch07` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cacheApi,
  ws,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0",
  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29",
  "com.github.scullxbones" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-common" % "3.0.5",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-query" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-typed" % "2.6.10",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-guice" % "2.8.7"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=1.3.10
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
name := """pla-memcache-example"""
organization := "com.example"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.13.3"

val appDependencies = Seq(
    guice,
    play.PlayImport.cacheApi,
    "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0",
    "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.0.0" % Test
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala).settings(
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
    resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2" // required to resolve `spymemcached`, the plugin's dependency.
  )
```

plugins.sbt

```
sbt.version=1.3.13
```

plugins.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")
```

In this case, first find the giter8 template and use the "sbt new" command.
Next, go to the official page of the plugin and check the name of the library, and then use Maven search to find the version you want to use.
It's a good idea to read the entire readme of the plugin without skipping it.

You can also try to run sbt with commands instead of using IntelliJ.
If that doesn't solve the problem, you can try clearing the cache in the .ivy2 directory.

Reference Links:
https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached
https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-seed.g8
https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.mumoshu/play2-memcached-play28_2.13/0.11.0/jar

Comment: Can you present the full build.sbt, plugins.sbt, build.properties ?

Comment: I've added a lot of information, so please take a look.

Comment: * What is giter8 and why do I suddenly need it? * Why do I need to specify `guice` (it is used as a dependency in previous versions of build.sbt, and I did not have to specify it explicitly)? * I simply specified `cacheApi` in my build.sbt + the memcached jar version, and it seems to compile the memcached code, however the path of `cacheApi` seems to be `play.sbt.cacheApi`... so why do I need `play.PlayImport.cacheApi` and what does it do? * Why can't I have a simple `build.sbt` structure with: scala version, required repos, libraryDependencies, and that's it?

Comment: In order to identify the problem, it is easier to build a simple environment, make sure it works, and then compare the environment that works and the environment that doesn't work to get to the answer.
Since I wanted to remove uncertainty for verification purposes, I added only the contents described in the readme of the plugin to the project generated by the template, and did not change any other parts.
There are many scala project templates available on giter8. Here I'm looking for a simple play project and using it.
Guice is a must when using Play2.8.

Comment: So you know where in the Play 2.8 documentation it is mentioned that it's necessary to explicitly include Guice?

Comment: It certainly wasn't mentioned in the documentation.
I'll ask the maintainer about it separately, as it may be a flaw in the documentation.

Comment: I made an Issue and PR about it. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/10614

Comment: https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached wrote that in Play 2.6.x and newer, we need to add the dependency `play.PlayImport.cacheApi` — that's also what you did. But with Play 2.8.7, while compiling I'm getting: `build.sbt: error: object PlayImport is not a member of package play`... however, when I simply add `cacheApi`, it does compile. According to intellij, this is actually `play.sbt.PlayImport.cacheApi`... is it an error in the documentation then?

Comment: I went back and checked the migration guide, and it seems that the changes were already made in version 2.4. I'll put up an Issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is when trying to import `play.sbt.PlayImport.cache`. According to [Cache APIs Migration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/CacheMigration26) by play:

> ### New packages
>
> Now `cache` has been split into a `cacheApi` component with just the API, and `ehcache` that contains the Ehcache implementation. If you are using the default Ehcache implementation, simply change `cache` to `ehcache` in your `build.sbt`:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>   ehcache
> )
> ```
>
> If you are defining a custom cache API, or are writing a cache implementation module, you can just depend on the API:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>   cacheApi
> )
> ```
>
> ### Removed APIs
>
> The deprecated Java class play.cache.Cache was removed and you now must inject an play.cache.SyncCacheApi or play.cache.AsyncCacheApi.

Therefore a complete `build.sbt` will be:

```
name := "CH07"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `ch07` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "https://files.couchbase.com/maven2"

val appDependencies = Seq(
  play.sbt.PlayImport.ehcache,
  play.sbt.PlayImport.cacheApi,
  "com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play28" % "0.11.0"
  //"com.github.mumoshu" %% "play2-memcached-play26" % "0.9.2"
)
val main = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.sbt.PlayScala).settings(
  version := version.value,
  libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies,
  resolvers += "Spy Repository" at "https://files.couchbase.com/maven2" // required to resolve `spymemcached`, the plugin's dependency.
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  //cache,
  ws,

  "org.hsqldb" % "hsqldb" % "2.5.0",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-codegen-maven" % "3.14.4",
  "org.jooq" % "jooq-meta" % "3.14.4",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.7",
  "com.github.scullxbones" %% "akka-persistence-mongo-common" % "3.0.5",
  "com.ning" % "async-http-client" % "1.9.29"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

`build.properties`:

```
sbt.version=1.4.4
```

`plugins.sbt`:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.7")
```

Comment: Some things don't make sense. * If I use memcached implementation of the cacheApi , why do I need ehcache implementation? * my code compiles without specifying `Typesafe repository`, so why do I need to specify it? * I don't understand what the `val main = ..` is good for. We don't use `main` later. Is `main` a keyword in sbt? * I was able to get the project to compile just with specifying dependencies in `libraryDependencies ++= Seq(...)`, so why do I need `appDependencies` and `main` at all?   * Why do I need to repeat twice on `(project in file("."))`? And what is the meaning of this code?

Comment: @rapt, I am not familiar with `memcached`, so I am not sure why do you need both `memcached` and `cacheApi`. My general intent in this answer is to provide the closest `build.sbt` to the one you tried to generate, but that do compile. I specified the resolver in `plugins.sbt` because this is auto generated from play. So I just didn't remove it. You can remove it if you want. main is not reserved word in this context. We use it here in order to enable play. Otherwise it is hard to load the plugin.

Comment: You can definitely merge `appDependencies` with `libraryDependencies`. As said before I tried to keep it with your structure. `(project in file("."))` means the project located at the top hierarchy. You don't need it twice. You can choose one of them. Just make sure you are enabling play plugin

Comment: Did you mean "why do you need both memcached and ehcache"?

Comment: @rapt I hope that makes things clearer. If needed I can simplify the `build.sbt` and not stick with your conventions.

Comment: * Generally, a well-designed and well-documented library should not force you to be familiar with its internals in order to add its library and use some basic methods and get it to compile (that's the idea of library). I wonder why the memcached doc @ github is so messy and inaccurate. Couldn't they just post a simple hello world project with a clean and working build.sbt? I think I don't need both both memcached and ehcache. Based on your explanation what is the API and what is the implementation, I have the dependencies `cacheApi` and `..."play2-memcached-play28"...` and it seems to compile.

Comment: * It's nice to know why I don't need to specify a resolver, and where it is defined regardless. * Can you explain what `(project in file("."))`, `.enablePlugins(PlayScala)`, `val main =`, `lazy val ch07 =`, `:=`, `routesGenerator :=` mean (if you think you know)? Or direct me to where it is explained? (I got a book on sbt, but it's quite outdated, and I also thought reading a book for a "dependency manager" system should be considered an overkill).

Comment: Anyway, I would like to reduce the build.sbt to the minimum that is intuitive and still working. That is, scala version, required repos, libraryDependencies, and that's all. * I have updated my post with the build.sbt that currently compiles (however upgrading play to 2.8.7 made a lot of the play API used in the project non-working, so I'm still working to upgrading the API calls).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226391/discussion-between-tomer-shetah-and-rapt).